# What should I do if my university is not in anabin?

Tags: germany, medicine

My university is not listed in [Anabin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabin) - a website run by German education officials, listing foreign universities that have been evaluated for their comparability with German universities. The fact that my university is not listed is odd, because far less recognized universities are listed there. I'm gonna start my medical career in Germany, should I worry about this?

Comment: Please do explain "anabin"...

Comment: From their website: "a large number of people have already applied for their foreign qualifications to be recognised by ZAB – each time this happens, the institution, degree type and specific degree is added to the Anabin database and you can use these entries as proof of your degree recognition if they align with your qualifications. However, if no one has previously requested for your qualification to be recognised, then your institution, degree type and specific degree will not be listed on Anabin and you will have to officially apply for a Statement of Comparability from ZAB. "

Comment: So now what is “ZAB”?

Comment: @EdV Zentralstelle für ausländisches Bildungswesen - "The Central Office for Foreign Education (ZAB) is the central authority for the evaluation of foreign qualifications in Germany."

Comment: @Anyon Thanks! Bit of a shame such a nice name gets compressed down to a three letter acronym! ;-)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I think that you might want to expand that out into a proper answer rather than answering in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Direct copy&paste from a [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176594/what-should-i-do-if-my-university-is-not-in-anabin#comment474640_176594)

> From their website: "a large number of people have already applied for
> their foreign qualifications to be recognised by ZAB – each time this
> happens, the institution, degree type and specific degree is added to
> the Anabin database and you can use these entries as proof of your
> degree recognition if they align with your qualifications. However, if
> no one has previously requested for your qualification to be
> recognised, then your institution, degree type and specific degree
> will not be listed on Anabin and you will have to officially apply for
> a Statement of Comparability from ZAB. "

Comment: Where ZAB stands for *Zentralstelle für ausländisches Bildungswesen*, which is *The Central Office for Foreign Education (ZAB) is the central authority for the evaluation of foreign qualifications in Germany*.
( thanks to Q&A in comments https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176594/what-should-i-do-if-my-university-is-not-in-anabin/176697#comment474658_176594 and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176594/what-should-i-do-if-my-university-is-not-in-anabin/176697#comment474651_176594 )